# Extjs treeview getselected method not working

Tags: extjs, treeview

I'm using a extjs 2 treeview to filter based on a checkbox selection but the `tree.getSelected()` method does not work correctly.

The problem is that, if a parent node is selected it gets that parent node only and doesn't get its children. I have an exact duplicate of the code but in extjs 4 that works 100%

**(EXTJS 2 Code)**

```
var records = Ext.getCmp('My_Custom_Tree').getChecked(),
    names = [];

Ext.Array.each(records, function (rec) {
    names.push([rec.raw.type, rec.raw.text]);
});
```

**(EXTJS 4 Code)**

```
var records = Ext.getCmp('My_Custom_Tree').getView().getChecked(),
    names = [];

Ext.Array.each(records, function (rec) {
    names.push([rec.raw.type, rec.raw.text]);
});
```

If anyone can tell me if there is a bug with the get selected or provide an alternative besides upgrading to 4 it would be appreciated.